# PHP: How to pass "current $_FILE" to another function after iterate $_FILES global variable?

Tags: php, file-upload

If I submit a form with multiple files in it, how can I upload each of them after some kind of execution one by one?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this to your PHP page

```
//upload image 1
if ($filename1<>"") {
    $filename = $filename1;
    $file = 'file1';
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
    include "upload_file.php";
    $updateimageurl = mysql_query("update yacht set image1 = '$newfilename' where yachtid = '$yachtid'");
}
//upload image 2
if ($filename2<>"") {
    $filename = $filename2;
    $file = 'file2';
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file2"]["name"]);
    include "upload_file.php";
    $updateimageurl = mysql_query("update yacht set image2 = '$newfilename' where yachtid = '$yachtid'");
}
```

And then the file called "upload_file.php should look something like this (change the validation sections if you want it to validate on different file names). Also, this renames the file to a random name before saving it to your location);

```
<?php

$length = 30;
$characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$code = "";
for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $pos = mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1);
    $code .= $characters{$pos};
}

$parts = explode('.',$filename);
$extension= end($parts);

$newfilename=$code .".".$extension;
$success = 0;



$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES[$file]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES[$file]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES[$file]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES[$file]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES[$file]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES[$file]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES[$file]["size"] < 1000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {


    $filenamepng = "./images/yacht/".$code.".png";
    $filenamegif = "./images/yacht/".$code.".gif";
    $filenamejpeg = "./images/yacht/".$code.".jpeg";
    $filenamejpg = "./images/yacht/".$code.".jpg";
    $filenamepjpeg = "./images/yacht/".$code.".pjpeg";
    $filenamexpng = "./images/yacht/".$code.".x-png";

    if (file_exists($filenamepng)||file_exists($filenamegif)||file_exists($filenamejpeg)||file_exists($filenamejpg)||file_exists($filenamepjpeg)||file_exists($filenamexpng)) {
      if (file_exists($filenamepng)) {
        $dir = './images/yacht/';
        $filename = $dir.$code.'.png';
        unlink($filename);
      }
      if (file_exists($filenamegif)) {
        $dir = './images/yacht/';
        $filename = $dir.$code.'.gif';
        unlink($filename);
      }
      if (file_exists($filenamejpeg)) {
        $dir = './images/yacht/';
        $filename = $dir.$code.'.jpeg';
        unlink($filename);
      }
      if (file_exists($filenamejpg)) {
        $dir = './images/yacht/';
        $filename = $dir.$code.'.jpg';
        unlink($filename);
      }
      if (file_exists($filenamepjpeg)) {
        $dir = './images/yacht/';
        $filename = $dir.$code.'.pjpeg';
        unlink($filename);
      }
      if (file_exists($filenamexpng)) {
        $dir = './images/yacht/';
        $filename = $dir.$code.'.x-png';
        unlink($filename);
      }
    }

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"],
      "images/yacht/" . $newfilename);
      //echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    unset($code);
    $success = 1;
}
else
{
    $error = "Your image is over 1mb OR is not in an accepted format; gif, jpeg, jpg, pjpeg, x-png, or png. Please try again.";
}
?>
```

[www.clubtray.com](http://www.clubtray.com)
[www.clubtray-clubmembershipsoftware.com](http://www.clubtray-clubmembershipsoftware.com)